# Unicorn serialized files whose items are edited through SPE are not listed in source control pending changes

Tags: powershell-extensions, unicorn

We are running Sitecore powershell script to update a item's field. Respective yaml files are generated in web root folder. But not showing in TFS pending changes. On the other hand, if we are changing any items manually, those yaml files are appearing in pending changes list.

Can you please help to list the SPE generated yaml files appeared in pending changes.

Comment: Can you make sure that the yaml files are generated to same place when using powershell script and when doing it manually.

Comment: Yes Jon. The same place where SPE updated and manually updated yaml files are presented.

Comment: When you are talking about TFS pending changes`? What do you mean exactly? Do you happen to be talking about version control through Git?

Comment: Yes Jon. We are using TFS as source control